Custom shower - where should drywall end?
I am having someone build me a shower but I don't quite understand if where he finished the Hardie backer is correct. I assumed it was supposed to end above the shower lip.

Anywhere that gets wet every time the shower is used should have cement backer board. But contractors will often use shortcuts. A full sheet of cement board probably only got them this far, and it was more work to add another piece. Good luck getting them to fix this. Read the fine print of your contract.

There isn't an exact stop or start place when talking about your backerboard to drywall transition.
I generally backer until about 6' high.  And generally 2-3 inches outside of the shower or tub.    There are some logistics to this.    Thankfully I tell my designer to get on the same page as me and we make the rules.   Some general rules I have...

tile should overlap the transition by at least a couple inches.    I don't want tile to end right where my backer ends.    You will end up with a cracked wall seam no matter what... eventually.

you should never have sliver seams.   I won't allow a piece of drywall or backer to be cut into a less than 2" seam but more likely I want at least 6".

You always always always want 2x4s covering the entrance to all tubs and showers on both sides to attach doors, curtains or whatever.   I don't care if you are planning a door.   Always.   If the threshold is 6" I will put three flipped 2x4s back to back to back on each side.

You do not want to install things on the transition from drywall to backboard.   So for example if the shower door was rather thick (wide?) and was installed on the outer part of the threshold I would not want the backerboard meeting the drywall right on the outer part.   I would prefer at least 2" but in reality 6".


Some obvious issues I see with this picture...

Not sure I have every seen drywall used in the inside of shower pans (yes I know kerdi allows this in some cases but there are not many installers that can install that correctly).

I can for the life of me figure out how that sliver of a half inch of drywall would ever be acceptable next to the threshold.   There is no way that sliver will hold up and will surely deform.    So even if it were backerboard, you can have a sliver of any type of material at such a delicate spot.   The bottom corners of showers are for sure the most vulnerable spot of the install.   This drives me batshit crazy.   You have to plan.    I am guessing your shower is 3' wide.    And they stood a backer piece up.    YOU CANT DO THAT ON SHOWERS!!!    Showers you install the backer pieces horizontally on the ends so you do have a seam near the shower pan.

The backerboard is butted to the shower pan.   There should be a generous 1/8" gap there for drainage and flow (and expansion).

It looks as if the backerboard was cut on the bottom side.   What?    Why would I introduce spurs and threads that might effect the flatness of the tile install.


What would my install look like?   I would prefer the backboard about 2" outside the threshold.   I would like the tile to extend to at least 6" outside the threshold.   That way I am hiding my transition under tile and 6" out means I should be able to deal with leveling issues without effecting the tile too much (I don't want slightly tilted tiles on door frames).   And this is obviously easy by installing backerboard horizontally and notching it for the threshold.

The cement board should have come to the outer edge of the curb or beyond. ( see the blue line.)

Where there is drywall will still be in the wet area and can be future problems.
Also if you are planning a shower door or glass, the area of attachment sometimes requires a minimum of a 2x4 with cement board sheathing. Many of the local custom shower glass companies in my area will not instal over drywall backed tile.

Thank you, that is very helpful!
